# Can I write a DDL trigger in SQL Server 2008 to auto create keys based on column name?

Tags: sql-server-2008, triggers, ddl

I've never written a DDL trigger, but my understanding is that they run SQL when the schema changes.  I am looking to streamline the repetitive tasks. I'm not sure if they are really only designed for auditing purposes.

- For an int field [id] in the first ordinal position:

  - make it the primary key
  - set the identity seed/increment is 1
- For a varchar field [name] in the second ordinal position:

  - make it a unique key

Basically, the question is: Are DDL triggers in SQL Server 2008 a good match for what I want to do? (And, if you already do this and have the sql code right there, could you please paste it in?)

Comment: i try to accept when an answer helps me; that would keep the quality up if everyone did the same right?  i'll take a look though as i do want to be fair.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No DDL triggers are not a good match for what you want to do.

DDL Triggers run *after* the table is already created.

A column cannot have the `identity` property added on retrospectively which would mean that your trigger would need to use dynamic SQL to immediately drop the newly created table and recreate it.

Even assuming that this is just for a personal project so you don't have fellow developers to worry about surprising and are not bothered about the inefficiency aspect generating the `create` script would be difficult to do robustly whether you try and start from scratch or parse the `CommandText` as a starting point.

If this is a common pattern for you then you might want to investigate creating a custom `CREATE TABLE` template in SSMS's template explorer.

Comment: thanks for the tip.  by dynamic sql do you mean building a tsql string or inserting rows to the information_schema views?

Comment: Dynamic SQL involves building a TSQL string you cannot change the table structure by modifying these views.